# php_apc crashes apache with xampp

Tags: php, apache, xampp, apc

As stated in title, heres some info of what im using>

xampp ver: 3.1.0

php ver: 5.4.7

apc ver: APC 3.1.9 for PHP 5.4 vc9 (Win7/2008)

web server: using local pc as webserver (windows 8)

found this error in apache log everytime i turned apc on:

> [mpm_winnt:crit] [pid 6112:tid 308] AH00419: master_main: create child process failed. Exiting.

anyone know whats happening or at least tell me am i using the correct version? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

APC doesn't support PHP 5.4 until version 3.1.10.

Currently, the newest APC version is [3.1.13](http://pecl.php.net/package/APC).

I would also recommend to take a look at [APCu](https://github.com/krakjoe/apcu), which is an API-compatible replacement for APC without the compile cache component. It works fine in conjunction with Zend OPcache that is bundled in PHP 5.5+.

Comment: I changed to apc version 3.1.13 beta, but my browser now cant even display localhost now, means the server is not running even though xampp doesnt show any error, i double check the port, its 80..when i turn off apc, its all normal again..

Comment: sorry for my own carelessness, it was an error in php ini. My ini set apc.shm_size = **64** , the correct 1 is apc.shm_size = **"64M"**

Answer (score 0):

Look at your phpinfo, look for the "Zend Extension Build". mine is like "API220100525,TS,VC9". TS means its a Thread safe version if its NTS its not thread safe version.
Download the binaries of APC according to your PHP version, there will be two directories TS and NTS copy the php_apc.dll from the appropriate folder and place it in the php\ext folder

write this in your php.ini file at the bottom.

```
[APC]
extension=php_apc.dll
apc.enabled = 1
apc.shm_segments = 1
apc.shm_size = "64M"
apc.max_file_size = "10M"
apc.stat = 1
```

Restart your apache server.